# How to Delete all #Temp Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

Let's pretend 10 different people create 10 different #temp tables.

Is there a way to delete all of these tables? These 10 people never log out of their current session. It is my understanding they auto delete after they log out, but wanted to see if there was a way to delete mine and everyone else's without them logging out.

Comment: See https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Kill their session!

Comment: @Stu "..without them logging out."

Comment: Teach them to close their sessions. This is a user issue, not a software issue; aka a PICNIC (Problem In Chair, Not In Computer).

Comment: Why do you want to? Are they taking up too much space? `#` tables won't name-clash with anyone else's

Comment: They are taking up too much space.

Comment: Life has taught me users are stupid, no matter where you go, so I want to just do it for them.

Comment: It seemed like a DDL trigger on `create_table` might let you stop creation of the problem tables. Nope. Not even on database `tempdb`. You're welcome to continue down the rabbit hole: [Tracking Temp Tables using DDL triggers](https://www.bradmckuhen.com/2015/05/tracking-temp-tables-using-ddl-triggers.html). Don't forget to test `select`/`into` statements.

Comment: Limit the growth of tempdb, if there ain't space they gotta play ball lol. Or move it to a usb 1.0 flash drive

Comment: @HABO If I *really* wanted to go down the rabbit-hole, I'd probably go for a session kill after a certain amount of time.